# Using Log Likelihood to Find Sufficient Statistic

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

So, I've been given the following problem from Wackerly's *Mathematical Statistics with Applications* (specifically 9.60). I'm aware of one way to find the solution, but I'd like to know if this works as well.

Let $Y_1 ... Y_n$ be a random sample from

$$f(y|\theta) = \begin{cases} \theta y^{\theta - 1}, & 0 < y < 1, & \theta > 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}   \end{cases}$$

Show that $$\sum^n_{i=1} -\text{log}(y_i)$$ is sufficient for $\theta$.

The second part is showing that it is an uniformly minimum-variance unbiased estimator, but I'm not really that worried about that part. I'll go through my logic to showing it so far.

$$L(y_i) = \prod^n_{i=1}\theta y_i^{\theta -1} = \theta^n\prod_{i=1}^n y_i^{\theta - 1}$$
At this point, I can see that maybe I could use the log-likelihood function instead of the typical likelihood function. I'm just not sure if I can do this.

If we find the sufficient statistic by expressing our Likelihood function as $h(y)g(T(y))$ then our log likelihood would expressed as $h(x) + g(T(x))$.
So, I have
$$l(y_i) = n\text{log}(\theta) +\theta\sum^n_{i=1}\text{log}(y_i) - \sum^n_{i=1}\text{log}(y_i)$$
$$=n\text{log}(\theta) +(1-\theta)\big(-\sum^n_{i=1}\text{log}(y_i)\big)$$
So, our $h(y)$ could be the $n\text{log}(\theta)$ and the $g(T(y))$ could be $(1-\theta)\big(-\sum^n_{i=1}\text{log}(y_i)\big)$ where $T(y)$ is $\big(-\sum^n_{i=1}\text{log}(y_i)\big)$.

Basically, what I'm asking... Is this legitimate?

Comment: As a start, please look at Wikipedia on 'beta distribution', section 3 (parameter estimation). What member of the beta family do you have here?

Comment: It appears to be of Beta$(\theta, 1)$, or so I think.

Comment: That's it. And you have only one parameter to estimate. When reading Wikipedia, the secret is to focus just on what you need--if it's there. Why do you doubt the validity of your result?

Comment: It was less a worry about the result and more a worry about the method I used to obtain my result.